# Can tell somebody how to add Slick vue component in Laravel, step by step?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, slider, slick.js

I have an issue with Laravel and Vue.js.

I can't understand how to add [vue-slick](https://github.com/staskjs/vue-slick) to my blade in **Laravel 5**.

Read how to use it [here](https://vuejsexamples.com/vue-component-for-slick-carousel/)  (why someone thinks that is good documentation)

My steps:

- Install the package by NPM (`npm install vue-slick`)
- Add new component Vue and now, I don't know what to do.

Where do I add code of script? To `app.js` or to `example.vue`?

Big thanks.

Comment: can i see something what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember the exact setup when installing Laravel 5 (although a quick look at Github gave me some memories), but assuming the `ExampleComponent.vue` component is correctly imported into `app.js`, you should be able to use it in any blade file like this `<example-component></example-component>`, and then the easiest way to use `vue-slick` would be to edit the `ExampleComponent.vue` file like this:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <slick ref="slick" class="gallery-container" :options="slickOptions">
            <div class="gallery-item" v-for="picture in pictures" :key="picture.key">
                <img :src="picture.src" class="img-fluid" alt="option image">
            </div>
        </slick>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Slick from 'vue-slick';
    export default {
        components: {
           Slick
        },
        data() {
            return {
                slickOptions: {
                    slidesToShow: 3,
                    slidesToScroll: 1,
                },
                pictures: [
                {
                    key: 'img1',
                    src: '/images/pic1.jpg'
                },
                {
                    key: 'img2',
                    src: '/images/pic2.jpg'
                },
                {
                    key: 'img3',
                    src: '/images/pic3.jpg'
                }]
            };
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```